# Nested NSManagedObjectContext's and NSFetchedResultsController for relationships

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Trying to implement add/save controller for my CoreData entity with buttons save and cancel using MagicalRecord.

```
- (void)addProduct
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];

    [context MR_setWorkingName:@"PRODUCT_ADD_MOC"];

    ProductBaseEntity *entity = [ProductBaseEntity MR_createInContext:context];
    [self presentProductSaveControllerWithEntity:entity andContext:context];
}

- (void)editProduct:(ProductBaseEntity *)entity
{
    [self presentProductSaveControllerWithEntity:entity andContext:nil];
}

- (void)presentProductSaveControllerWithEntity:(ProductBaseEntity *)entity
                                    andContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)parentContext
{
    if (!parentContext) {
        parentContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextWithParent:parentContext];
    [context MR_setWorkingName:@"PRODUCT_SAVE_MOC"];

    ProductBaseEntity *contextEntity = (ProductBaseEntity *)[context objectWithID:entity.objectID];

    ProductSaveController *controller = [[ProductSaveController alloc] initWithEntity:contextEntity];

    controller.managedObjectContext = context;

    controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                                  target:controller
                                                                                  action:@selector(cancel)];

    controller.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save"
                                                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                                   target:controller
                                                                                   action:@selector(done)];

    [controller setDoneHandler:^(ProductSaveController *saveController) {
        if (context.hasChanges) {
            [context MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }];
        } else {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }];

    [controller setCancelHandler:^(ProductSaveController *saveController) {
        if (context.hasChanges) {
            [OHAlertView showAlertWithTitle:@"Really exit?"
                                    message:@"Exit and discard changes?"
                               cancelButton:@"Cancel"
                                   okButton:@"Exit"
                             onButtonTapped:^(OHAlertView *alert, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
                                 if (buttonIndex == 1) {
                                     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                 }
                             }];
        } else {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }];

    [self presentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller] animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

First part of question is: did this implementation looks good? I create separated context for save controller and later i can decide: should i save changes in persistent store (save button) or should i just throw away changes without modifying persistent store (cancel button). For addProduct i create one more context because if i call `context.hasChanges` it gives me `YES` anyway because object was inserted to this context.

Btw this part of my code work just great.

In `ProductSaveController` i have button which open `SomeController` with list of related to `ProductBaseEntity` entities (1:M) called `ProductEntity` using `NSFetchedResultsController`.

```
_fetchedResultsController = [ProductEntity MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"position"
                                                     ascending:YES
                                                 withPredicate:predicate
                                                       groupBy:nil
                                                      delegate:self
                                                     inContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Where `self.managedObjetContext` is context from `presentProductSaveControllerWithEntity` method. Problem is that my controller doesn't reflect changes in this controller. For example i do:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        ProductEntity *entity = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [entity MR_deleteInContext:_fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext];
    }
}
```

And i have nothing! This row from tableView doesn't hide! But if i click back button and open this controller again i see changes! If i move from `self.managedObjectContext` to mainQueue context my fetchedResultsController work as expected. Does NSFetchedResultsController should work with private queue contexts??

Answer (score 0):

You're deleting the entity, but it looks like you're not responding to the delete and updating your view. You can typically do this by implementing NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate on your view controller

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController work just if i use MR_defaultContext. It seems NSFRC has problems with private queue contexts.